# how to get user info using old REST api

Tags: php, facebook

I want user's basic information for use in my facebook app. so i use following code:

$query = "SELECT uid,first_name, name,pic_big FROM user WHERE uid
IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= '$user') order by rand() LIMIT $numberoffriends;";

$friendsrand = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($query);

var_dump($friendsrand);

This code works fine one week before but now it returns nothing (empty).

Please help me where i m wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the PHP SDK there is a function called getInfo which may work for you:

```
$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($uid, 'first_name, sex, etc...');
```

However, I (and Facebook itself) suggest you switch to the new Graph API as soon as you can, since the old REST API is becoming deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I alreay used users_getInfo but it returns nothing (empty). Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Well, I guess this is the only solution. I don't know if this has something to do with the old REST api becoming deprecated, but as I said I suggest you to switch to the new API if you have the chance to.